# User/Role/Module based architecture

Tags: java, architecture

I need to build an application that will be based on user roles and preferences. Similar to facebook or google widgets, where a user can add/remove apps. In additions, there will be preconfigured apps loaded automatically.

Is there a generic tool/framework that would facilitate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't seen a generic tool for that, but...

....I have seen this case implemented ("reinvented and reprogrammed") several times. I have see that some of the newest libraries and frameworks, have their own access rights implemented (example: asp.net).

You didn't mention or tagged if you already choose an existing programming framework, for your application, maybe you already have in mind a framework, and maybe that framework has some libraries to control how and what modules, can a user access.

Usually, a set of libraries for this, is separated in two sections.

One section is a data access layer, that store the users, roles and access rights for each role or user. Usually is a set of tables in the application's database. But, can be also some configuration files, like XML.

The other section of code has to do with the logical or user interface layer, and that is very specific to the programming language and programming framework you are using, that's why I think there is not a generic tool.